# OpenCL and Direct3D for Intel GPU

Tags: opencl, direct3d

My PC CPU is Intel i5-5200U with HD Graphics 5500 whose driver version is 20.19.15.4331.OS is winndow 10.

PC camera captures video ,video shows directly with Direct3D. Now I add the OpenCL to code to process the video. After that,Video shows.there is no interaction between OpenCL and Direct3D. They are independent of each other . and different threads run the OpenCL and Direct3D code. PresentationInterval of D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS is D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_THREE.

There is a problem : when I delete the OpenCL process( that means video show directly), GPU driver will stop and intel GPU will reset (PresentEx is timeout). I find clReleaseCommandQueue casuses this problem. if No clReleaseCommandQueue , there is no problem. and I change the PresentationInterval value from D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_THREE to D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_TWO(more than one is ok), these is no problem too. Update GPU driver with version 15.40.22.64.4424, these is no problem as well.

pls, someone can tell me why.

ps: for the same driver and same code for another pc with intel HD4600, there is no problem.

Comment: DirectCompute is designed to interop smoothly with Direct3D 11/Direct3D 12, so did you consider going that route instead of trying to get OpenCL to interop with Direct3D?

Comment: it's a complicated choice for interop. Not all the video data will process with OpenCL, But all of them will be showed through Direct3D 9. And if interoperate between OpenCL and Direct3D, So many code need refine, that is impossible for us.

Comment: Why in particular are you using the legacy Direct3D 9 API?